# plotting the mean and standard deviation of data when there is more than one piece of data collected at a particular point

Tags: matlab, plot, mean, standard-deviation

I have a matrix, in one columnn is the day of year and in the other is the data associated with that day of year. On some days of the year there are multiple data points, while others there is one or none. This makes it difficult to plot the information, what I would like to do is plot the data based on the mean and standard deviation of the data. So if data was collected three times on the 320th day of the year then the mean and standard deviation of these three data points would be found out and then when plotted the mean line would go through the mean and the standard deviation would represent error bars. So just say the data is:

```
DOY     DATA

30,     12

30,     10

30,     8

120,    6

110,    5
```

I'd Like to transform it to:

```
DOY   DATA   STD

30,   10,     2

120,   6,      0

110,   5,      0
```

I then wish to plot this data with the standard deviation representing error bars.
How would I go about this?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a mock example of your data matrix

Comment: Edited my question to include an example, thanks

Comment: Why `370` and not `30`??

Comment: Sorry, I meant 30! thanks for the pick up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `accumarray` especially if you don't have the stats toolbox:

```
doy = [30 30 30 120 110]';
data = [12 10 8 6 5]';

[~,ind,subs] = unique(DOY);

means = accumarray(subs, data, size(ind), @mean);
stds = accumarray(subs, data, size(ind), @std);

final = [DOY(ind), means, stds]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Matlab's `dataset` to get easy grouping -

```
>> doy = [30 30 30 120 110]';
>> data = [12 10 8 6 5]';
```

The next line creates a `dataset` object with two columns, called "doy" and "data"

```
>> ds = dataset(doy, data);
```

This line says to calculate group statistics, using "doy" as the grouping variable, and computing the mean and std for each group. It also gives you the number of variables in each group in the column `GroupCount`.

```
>> grpstats(ds, 'doy', {'mean', 'std'})
ans =
           doy    GroupCount    mean_data    std_data
    30      30    3             10           2       
    110    110    1              5           0       
    120    120    1              6           0
```